# Adding the latest WooCommerce products to the default WordPress blog feed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added this code to functions.php.

```
function rss_woo_latest($content) {
  
if( is_feed() ){
  
$args     = array( 'numberposts'=> 3,'orderby' => 'post_date','order' => 'DESC','post_type' => 'product' );
$products = get_posts( $args );
  
$content = $content.$products; 
  

}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_woo_latest');
add_filter('the_content', 'rss_woo_latest');
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect. Should I try modifying the feed.php directly?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to merge the woocommerce query with the main feed query. try below code in your theme's function.php file.

```
function add_woo_products_to_feed($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed() && class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        $number_of_products = 10;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $number_of_products,
        );
        $woocommerce_query = new WP_Query($args);

        // Merge the WooCommerce query with the main feed query
        $query->posts = array_merge($query->posts, $woocommerce_query->posts);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'add_woo_products_to_feed');
```

Above code will add the latest woocommerce products to default wordpress blog feed.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply - unfortunately I'm getting 'internal server error' 500 on the feed url